# No longer able to use ddescribe or iit

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I used to be able to use ddescribe and iit to have jasmine/karma run just a specific test or set of tests.  However, now it no longer works, and I get this error: (or a similar one for iit).

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:8081/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket jIMgciNEN5VXBdZOhDz2 with id 78471739
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ddescribe
  at /.../test.js:146
```

I am running: karma 0.12.28, jasmine 2.2.0, karma-jasmine: 0.3.5, karma-phantomjs-launcher: 0.1.4

Here is what the test file basically looks like:

```
'use strict';

ddescribe('MyController', function() {
    it('should do xyz', function() {
       ...
    });
});
```

Any ideas at all?  Is there some definition or configuration change that I have missed so that now ddescribe is no longer defined?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the bug report:  https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/73

Apparently they have changed from using **ddescribe** and **iit** to using **fdescribe** and **fit** for 'focused' testing.